# Best practice to use upload-able properties of a model in mvc code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm using MVC.Net with Code First and Entity Framework to build a website and one of my models have a document and a photo to be uploaded when creating an instance of it.
What's the best practice to deal with such models?
I used to store the name of any upload-able files in database after uploading them to a specific folder on the server and after naming them using Guid but I'm searching for any other better solution using MVC as I'm still new in using it.
I've checked for some solutions that uses HttpPostedFileBase property instead of the string one but I didn't get how it works and couldn't find a good sample that explains it.

I'm looking exactly on what's the best datatype that should be set to store the file or its name and what is the best method to take to upload and store it. And I want to get as much benefit as possible from the auto generated code for the controllers and views.

Any help or tutorial link would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

EDIT:
here is the code of the model I need to build...

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Document.Document), Name = "DocumentURI_DisplayName"]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Document.Document), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DocumentURI_RequiredErrorMessage")]
    public string DocumentURI { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Document.Document), Name = "PhotoURI_DisplayName"]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Document.Document), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhotoURI_MaxLengthErrorMessage")]
    public string PhotoURI { get; set; }
}
```

I need to know if I can use `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `string` for the `DocumentURI` and `PhotoURI` properties, and what is the best practice to deal with models with photos for instance.

Comment: Well, this question is very general. The best practice depends on a lot of things, like whether you want to store the file in the file system or in the database. Do you want the user to attach the file to a form, and submit it later with the form. Or, you want them to upload the file while submitting the form? Whatever you do, you can always bind the uploaded file to an HttpPostedFileBase object in your Model, or you can get the file from `Request.Files`.

Comment: the file should be uploaded while submitting the form, and it should be stored in the file system and only its name should be stored in a database. How can I use HttpPostedFileBase? when I used it in the model it gave an error while creating the database that it doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: I've edited the question to include some code

Comment: this is really question do i use Core DDD model Poco as MVC models.  in My view sure why not, but be prepared to used MVC Views, that are extra to the DDD model. You would then have a mapping layer in play some or all of the time.  Dont expect to use the DDD model exclusively in MVC.  The sample with uploading files is one where you might see a Different view model in MVC than DDD model. I will be interested to see if someone posts a "Best practice" response.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following links that might be helpful:

[ASP.NET MVC and File Uploads](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-and-File-Uploads.aspx)

[MVC3/EF4.1 Binding HttpPostedFileBase to model and adding to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305460/mvc3-ef4-1-binding-httppostedfilebase-to-model-and-adding-to-db)

[ASP.NET MVC Model containing File](http://098858.com/questions/17276953/asp-net-mvc-model-containing-file)